# Why does spectral class and U-V colour correlate slightly differently for main sequence, giant and supergiant stars?

Tags: spectra, observational-astronomy, classification, main-sequence, magnitude

[image: STAR CLASSIFICATION DIAGRAM]

In this diagram the $x$-axis is spectral type for stars and the $y$-axis is B-V colour.

Taking **Series 1** as the Main Sequence, **Series 2** as Giants and **Series 3** as Super-giants. Why the spectral class for all these stars differ from the other ones?

If we were to say differences, for instance, how would one express that information?

Comment: What is measured on the vertical axis?

Comment: Hi there.The vertical axis has the star colour B - V.

Comment: This question doesn't strike me as clear, but I think what's being asked is "Why do stars of the same spectral type have different colours at different brightnesses?" In his case, for example, a K5 dwarf has B-V=0.8ish, vs a K5 giant with B-V=1.1ish. (Based on the plot above. No idea where it comes from.)

Comment: This is clearly ***not*** the Hertzsprung Russell diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertzsprung%E2%80%93Russell_diagram

Comment: Okay, the vertical axis is the B-V colour index, as explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_index

Comment: The horizontal axis, spectral type, is explained in excruciating detail here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_types but none of the links I have so far provided actually answer your Q, they just make your Q clearer.

Comment: I believe the answer is buried here: http://www.handprint.com/ASTRO/specclass.html
I'll be back in a few days to explain.